# Tooltip in Datagrid

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

Is there any way to show the tooltip in Datagrid for more than 30 seconds?

example, here is my code
e.Item.Cells(7).Tooltip = e.Item.Cells(6).Text

on mousehover the tooltip will be displayed only 6 or 7 seconds, is there any way to increase the time for the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

These tooltips are a browser behavior that you have no control over.

Instead, you can use a custom Javascript tooltip, such as [this one](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/).